# Como enviar mensagens para as abas abertas de um app no chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensão

Estou consertando a parte de sincronização entre as abas abertas do meu app e lembrei que o Google Chrome tem uma API que se não me engano faz exatamente o que eu preciso, mandar mensagens internamente em um aplicativo.

Eu dei uma olhada no Google e no Chrome Developers e me confundi todo, então achei que seria melhor perguntar para quem já entende do assunto.

Eu preciso de um código que enviei mensagens para as abas abertas de um app (como já foi dito) e também como seria para receber essa mensagem.

Comment: Não sei quanto à API do Chrome, mas talvez [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) resolva (você precisa de uma referência a cada janela).

Answer (score 1):

Em um projeto recente foi necessário fazer algo parecido. Ele consistia em um sistema de contabilidade. Quando o usuário selecionasse outra empresa, todas as abas deveriam ser notificadas e atualizadas.

O sistema em questão foi implementado em JSF 2 com PrimeFaces, então usei o componente Push, que, por debaixo dos panos, usa o framework [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere).

[Este link](http://async-io.org/tutorial.html) contém um tutorial sobre o framework.